# вывести в строку заголовки шапки

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

[image: Шапка]

Подскажите пожалуйста, как вывести в строчку Home, Help и Sign in

Comment: Ruby on Rails тут ни при чём. Это проблема вёрстки и стилей, и вы не дали абсолютно никакой информации, чтобы её воспроизвести.

Answer (score 5):

`RR` тут не при чем, но на с `HTML` и `CSS` возможен такой вариант:

```css
.header {
background-color: #222222;
padding: 15px;
}

.header .header_item {
color: #5d5d5d;
display: inline-block;
font-family: Arial;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
<div class="header_item">Home</div>
<div class="header_item">Help</div>
<div class="header_item">Sign in</div>
</div>
```